# Как вернуть все элементы с querySelectorAll

Tags: javascript, запрос

У меня есть 5 инпута, нужно сделать так, чтобы если одно из них не заполнить, то сообщение не должно быть отправлено.

```js
document.querySelector(".btn-info").addEventListener("click", function(){
 var required = document.querySelectorAll(".required");
 if (required.val == "") {
  alert("please fill all the columns");
 }

});
```

```css
.required {
  display:block;
  padding-bottom:10x;
}
```

```html
<form id="fld">
  <input id="question1" class="required">
  <input id="question2" class="required">
  <input id="question3" class="required">
  <input id="question4" class="required">
  <input id="question5" class="required">
</form>
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-info">Отправить отзыв</button>
```

Comment: спрашиваешь про `querySelectorAll`, а в коде используешь `querySelector`

Comment: @Grundy прошу извинить я потестил все и случайно написал querySelector шас изменю

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Так как `querySelectorAll` возвращает **коллекцию** элементов, то проверка `required.val == ""` бессмысленна, ибо берется `val` (которого и одиночного-то элемента нет), которого в коллекции нет. Соответственно можно пробежать по коллекции и просмотреть значение `value` у элементов:

```js
document.querySelector(".btn-info").addEventListener("click", function(){
    let required = document.querySelectorAll(".required");
    let isAllFilled = true;
  
    for (let i = 0; i < required.length; ++i) {
        if (required[i].value.trim() == "") {
            isAllFilled = false;
            break;
 }
    }
  
    if (!isAllFilled)
        alert("please fill all the columns");
});
```

```css
.required {
  display:block;
  padding-bottom:10x;
}
```

```html
<form id="fld">
  <input id="question1" class="required">
  <input id="question2" class="required">
  <input id="question3" class="required">
  <input id="question4" class="required">
  <input id="question5" class="required">
</form>
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-info">Отправить отзыв</button>
```

Comment: спасибо за помощь

Comment: а почему вы используете стандарт ecmascript нельзя ли использовать просто js ?

Comment: @Carl .....Шта?

Comment: почему обявляете  переменную через let??@Алексей Шиманский

Comment: @Carl просто так захотелось

Comment: спасибо за ответ @Алексей Шиманский

Answer (score 4):

Альтернативным решением может стать использование атрибута `required` и псевдокласса [`:invalid`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Ainvalid) в селекторе.

В этом случае достаточно будет проверить, что такие элементы есть.

Пример:

```js
document.querySelector(".btn-info").addEventListener("click", function() {
  var required = document.querySelectorAll(".required:invalid");
  if (required.length) {
    console.log("please fill all the columns");
  }

});
```

```css
.required {
  display: block;
  padding-bottom: 10x;
}
```

```html
<form id="fld">
  <input id="question1" required class="required">
  <input id="question2" required class="required">
  <input id="question3" required class="required">
  <input id="question4" required class="required">
  <input id="question5" required class="required">
</form>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info">Отправить отзыв</button>
```

Comment: спасибо @Grundy но у меня библиотека подключена и такой подход не будет эффективен и просто невозможен HTML к измене не подлежит

Comment: @Carl, почему ты так думаешь? :)

Comment: я так не думаю я знаю @Grundy.Подключена библиотека и HTML генерируется сам по себе кроме элементов которых я написал.Ситуация такого что у каждого input-а есть массо классов поэтому давать дополнительный элемент не лучшая идея и плюс оно не будет рабтотать там но все равно спасибо что помог

Comment: @Carl, ты противоречишь себе: _HTML **генерируется сам** по себе **кроме элементов которых я написал**_. Единственное что нужно, это добавить в эти инпуты атрибут `required`. Не совсем понял про дополнительные элементы

Comment: если дать дополнительно required оно не будет работать.Так как это не простой инпут.Где  тут противоречия я не понял

Comment: @Carl, ты говоришь что менять не можешь html, потому что какую-то библиотеку используешь, а потом сказал, что эти инпуты ты пишешь сам. Ну и просто попробуй будет ли это работать или нет. И еще название библиотеки напиши :)

Comment: https://github.com/kartik-v/bootstrap-star-rating @Grundy вот библиотека который я использую вот то что я написал https://github.com/DuudeXX8/bootstrap-star-rating проблема такая что если одно из этих полей будут пустыми то при нажатии кнопки должно высвечиватся alert но при let ratingStars = document.querySelectorAll(".rating-stars") таком подходе в консоле разработчика показывает Cannot read property of undefined.Надеюсь обяснение  исчерпывающее

Comment: @Избытоксусликов, ты делаешь что-то странное. Код `document.querySelectorAll(".rating-stars")` **не может** показать _Cannot read property of undefined_.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69489/discussion-between-grundy-and--).

Answer (score 0):

Так как CSS псевдокласс `:required` выбирает все элементы с атрибутом required  то выборку можно сделать
`document.querySelectorAll(':required');`
При необходимости можно указать форму, в которой производится выборка
`document.querySelectorAll('#someForm :required');`
Проверку можно проводить валидацией форм, объяснение [здесь](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Learn/Forms/Form_validation).
Так, код можно организовать примерно:

```js
   
const btn = document.querySelector('button');
btn.addEventListener('click', event => {
    let reqd = document.querySelectorAll(':required');       
    reqd.forEach((el,ix) => {
        console.log('field for input ' + ix + ' valid = ' + el.validity.valid + ';\n');
    });
    return false;
});
```

```html
    <form id="fld" name="fld">
        <input id="question1" required>
        <input id="question2" required>
        <input id="question3" required>
        <input id="question4">
        <input id="question5" required>
    </form>
<button>Заполнено?</button>
```

Валидация осуществляется с помощью интерфейса Constraint validation API, о котором также можно почитать на [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Constraint_validation).